# $S_1$ and $S_2$ are two non intersecting circles with their centres at a distance 'd' apart.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles

Prove that the four points of intersection of DCT and TCT are concyclic. Also, find the radius of the circle.

So, drawing the diagram myself was very difficult on paper because the points of intersection were so close. Its pretty clear that diameter of the required circle is $d$. I was wondering if I could get a hint on how to prove that the points are concyclic. Thanks!

Here A is the center of $S_1$ and C is the center of $S_2$
[image]

Comment: Just show that the construction is symmetric with respect to the segment connecting centers. It follows that $\widehat{FGH}=\widehat{FIH}$, hence the proof.

Answer (score 0):

You've already noticed that $AC$ has to be the diameter. So, it is enough to show that $\angle AGC$ is $90$, and similarly with the other three angles.

> This comes from the fact that $AG$ and $CG$ are bisectors of supplementary angles.

Comment: Yea but the fact that AC is a diameter didn't occur to me until I plotted the curves on an engine which I guess is a cheat, is there a way that doesn't involve the fact that AC is a diameter?

Comment: @Parth Shresth I don't understand what a cheat means. The proof is totally legit regardless of how you realized that it has to be a diameter. It was also not hard to guess because the construction is symmetric with respect to $AC$.